# Cookies store seems to be not initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have rails 3.1 app with ruby 1.9.3-p286. In one of my before filters in ApplicationController I have `session_create_params = {deviceId: cookies.signed[:device_id]}`

When I'm calling some of my integration tests I get `undefined method [ ]' for nil:NilClass` Seems to cookies is nil. How can I fix this or what I'm doing wrong ?

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreatingSomeStuff < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
  end
  context 'When viewing some stuff' do
    setup do
      @some_url = 'http://www.google.com'
      visit("/stuff?url=#{@some_url}")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: log cookies.signed in your development log to see what its value is:

Rails.logger.info cookies.signed.inspect

Comment: `cookies.inspect => "nil"`

Comment: Can you post your integration test code? A possible reason why `cookies` is nil could be that the Rails environment has not been properly loaded by your test code, or it might be that the `cookies`  method is out of scope

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: Is `app` defined within your second `setup` block? You should be able to access the cookies object by calling `app.cookies`. Also, what is the value of `self` within that block?